# Is it possible to do a UNION like query with MagicalRecord/Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, union, magicalrecord

I have two Entities `Event` and `Action` which both inherit from `Message`. I've read that it's better for performance not to use single table inheritance. The events and actions are used in the app as an array of messages sorted by date. Currently I'm just selecting the events and actions separately then merging/sorting the new array.

```
    NSArray *events = [STEvent MR_findAll];
    NSArray *actions = [STAction MR_findAll];
    NSMutableArray *messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:events];
    [messages addObjectsFromArray:actions];
    NSArray *messagesSorted;
    messagesSorted = [messages sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
        NSDate *first = [(STMessage*)a date];
        NSDate *second = [(STMessage*)b date];
        return [first compare:second];
    }];
```

Is it possible to do a SQL UNION like query with Magical Record or Core Data to retrieve everything at once?

Comment: don't think so but id also like to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, I think you want to fetch all subclasses of `Message` in a single query. Thinking about it like this give you a clue to how to do this in code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [Message MR_requestAll];
request.includesSubentities = YES;
NSArray *eventsAndActions = [Message MR_executeFetchRequest:request];
//...continue on
```

This query will include all instances of `Message`, `Event` and `Action`, however.

Comment: doesn't answer 'Is it possible to do a SQL UNION like query with Magical Record or Core Data to retrieve everything at once?'

Answer (score 0):

#### Is it possible to do a SQL UNION like query with Magical Record or Core Data to retrieve everything at once?

No. Core Data is an object graph management framework. It may, or may not, have storage associated with it, and persistent stores are abstract object graph stores. You can't send SQL to a store, even if the concrete implementation of that store uses SQL or SQLite.

That said, given your object model, to get "everything" you would fetch all of your `Messages`. Use a predicate that will match everything you want (or a nil predicate) and use the `Messages` entity as the target of your fetch request. Your fetch will return all entities that descend from `Message`.